# Problem with IBM tutorial about an RSSReader

Tags: android, listview, callback

I have downloaded an IBM Android tutorial about how to develop an rss with android.

here's the url

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/tutorials/x-androidrss/

Seems to me it's a little old. I have insert new generics syntax but still have problems to compile at this lines

```
private void UpdateDisplay()
    {
        TextView feedtitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.feedtitle);
        TextView feedpubdate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.feedpubdate);
        ListView itemlist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.itemlist);


        if (feed == null)
        {
            feedtitle.setText("No RSS Feed Available");
            return;
        }

        feedtitle.setText(feed.getTitle());
        feedpubdate.setText(feed.getPubDate());

        ArrayAdapter<RssItem> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<RssItem>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,feed.getAllItems());

        itemlist.setAdapter(adapter);

        **itemlist.setOnItemClickListener(this);**

        itemlist.setSelection(0);

    }

    public void onItemClickListener(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id)
    {
     Log.i(tag,"item clicked! [" + feed.getItem(position).getTitle() + "]");

     Intent itemintent = new Intent(this,ShowDescription.class);

     Bundle b = new Bundle();
     b.putString("title", feed.getItem(position).getTitle());
     b.putString("description", feed.getItem(position).getDescription());
     b.putString("link", feed.getItem(position).getLink());
     b.putString("pubdate", feed.getItem(position).getPubDate());

     itemintent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.INTENT", b);

     //Replacing startSubActivity from the example
     startActivityForResult(itemintent,0);
    }
```

The compiler give me error here:

**itemlist.setOnItemClickListener(this);**

any idea? What's the correct way to do the callback?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you implement the `OnItemClickListener` interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cristian is on the right track but you have named your listener method incorrectly.This is wrong...

```
public void onItemClickListener(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id)
```

It should be...

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id)
```

Comment: sorry sorry sorry, solved it was the interface. Sorry and thanks